# Kafka producer not send out message even though batch.size is reached

Tags: apache-kafka

This is a Spring + Kafka application. The kafka config is as below. `batch.size=1` and `linger.ms = 20000`.

```
acks = 1
batch.size = 1
bootstrap.servers = [wqdcsrv3078.cn.infra:9093, wqdcsrv3079.cn.infra:9093, wqdcsrv3080.cn.infra:9095]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.id = mcd.client
compression.type = none
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
enable.idempotence = false
interceptor.classes = null
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
linger.ms = 20000
max.block.ms = 60000
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
max.request.size = 1048576
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 0
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.mechanism = SCRAM-SHA-256
security.protocol = SASL_PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
transactional.id = null
value.serializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

As you can see, the batch size is as small as 1. While running, the application produces a message whose payload is more than 500Kb.
From what I am thinking, whether the the batch size is reached, **or** the linger time is reached, the producer willl transfer this message to broke.

But while it is running, even the payload is 500Kb and batch size is reached, it still wait for around 20s to send out the message.

Why is the message not sent out immediately after reaching the batch size? Thanks.

Comment: It's not either, it's both batch and linger

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by both? Could you explain more? Thanks.

Comment: _even the payload is 500Kb and batch size is reached, it still wait for around 20s to send out the message_ - Because linger.ms=20000 is still applicable, regardless of the batch size

Comment: it is def a criptic answer